# Monorepo Typescript how to build package together?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, monorepo, esmodules

I have Pacakage 'A'
And app 'B'

**'Package A'**

```
index.ts
export default "foo"
```

A's package.json

```
main: index.ts
types: index.ts
```

A's tsconfig.json

```
 "module": "commonjs",
```

---

**'APP B'**

```
import value from "A"
```

B's pacakge.json

```
 "type": "commonjs",
```

B's tsconfig

```
 "module": "CommonJS",
```

My problem is that after typescript compile `App B`.

It generate plain `commonjs` which dosen't know how to use `export` keyword inside of `node_modules A`.

OK, I understand that.

If so, should I set the `main` of A's `package.json` as `index.js`?

If so, do I have to build every time `A` changes so that make sure `index.js` is updated?

That seems too handy....

Is it possible to make `package A` build together when `App B` is compiled?

Or any advice please...

Comment: what are you using to build? you probably needs some monorepo aware build tool like turborepo/rush/ nx. each tool will need to be configured to be aware of the dependency graph if it cannot be read from the package.json files of each project.

Comment: @user1852503 my tool is turborepo
Ok i will go and check turborepo's doc

Comment: @user1852503 I think... i need more hint. 
If this is only matter of "build" i would set "pip" of "turborepo" 
but i need to manage command "dev" which active watch mode.
should i build before start "dev " ?

Comment: @MINJAKIM did you figure it out in the end?

Comment: @Thomas Gak-Deluen Yes the answer was in typescript document. 
But none of the solution was fully filled my requirement.